# jquery ui - autocomplete - several parameters for input

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I wanted to do search the streets with autocomplete.
Select Province, city, street. Has a problem that based on the selected region and fetch parameter passed to the search of the city in a region. Later, the street on the basis of the parameter state and city.

Can someone explain what to change these relationships were maintained. At this moment I find work but without the dependencies.

file index.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
    $("#w1").autocomplete("get_w_list.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    minChars: 3,
    selectFirst: false

    });
    $("#m1").autocomplete("get_m_list.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    minChars: 3,
    selectFirst: false

    });
    $("#u1").autocomplete("get_u_list.php?", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    minChars: 3,
    selectFirst: false
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
    <form action="" autocomplete="off">
    <p>
    Województwo <label>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="w1" id="w1" />

    </p>
    <p>
    Miasto <label>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="m1" id="m1" />

    </p>
    <p>
    Ulica <label>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="u1" id="u1" />

    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

file get_w_list.php

```
    <?php
    require_once "config.php";
    $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
    if (!$q) return;

    $sql = "select DISTINCT woj from lb_mu where woj LIKE '%$q%'";
    mysql_query('SET CHARSET utf8');
    $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname = $rs['woj'];
    echo "$cname\n";
    }
    ?>
```

file get_m_list.php

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);

if (!$q) return;

$sql = "select DISTINCT miasto from lb_mu where miasto LIKE '%$q%'";
mysql_query('SET CHARSET utf8');
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
$mmname = $rs['miasto'];
echo "$mmname\n";
}
?>
```

Please help me solve this problem.
thx

Comment: Just so you know, this is not jQueryUI's autocomplete widget. It is using the predecessor of that plugin (which is now deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is right I would use the newer version of the plugin.  From what I can tell in your code you are calling different methods based on what they are searching for.  I'm not sure if this is necessary you can pass all the parameters in one method.  Syntax is a little rough but hopefully you get the idea.

```
var url = "get_list.php?w=" + $('#w1').val() + '&m=" + $('#m1').val();

$("#w1").autocomplete(url, {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    minChars: 3,
    selectFirst: false
});

<?php
require_once "config.php";
$m = strtolower($_GET["m"]);
$w = strtolower($_GET["w"]);

if m != ""
    $sql = "select DISTINCT woj from lb_mu where woj LIKE '%$q%'"
else if w != ""
    $sql = "select DISTINCT miasto from lb_mu where miasto LIKE '%$q%'"
else 
    return

}
?>
```